# Как мне настроить граф (отрисованный с graphvis) так, чтобы при загрузке html странички он отображался сразу в приближенном масштабе

Tags: python, css, json, graph, zoom

1.Пробовала zoom, но он убирает всю динамику графа и портит его качество. Мне правки нужно внести именно в html код (python кода у меня нет от данного графа)
2. Пробовала также через:
    /*  var afterzoomlimit = { //here we are setting the zoom limit to move to 
    scale: 1.8,
}*/
-не вышло

Вот код графа:

```
 // initialize global variables.
    var edges;
    var nodes;
    var network; 
    var container;
    var options, data;


    // This method is responsible for drawing the graph, returns the drawn network
    function drawGraph() {
        var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');

         // parsing and collecting nodes and edges from the python
nodes = new vis.DataSet([{"color": "#9b1118", "font": {"color": "black"}, "id": "\u0410-2003", "label": "\u0410-2003", "shape": "dot", "title": ""}, //здесь дальше очень много текста, его опустила
 edges = new vis.DataSet([{"from": "\u0410-2003", "to": "PDSA 2004"}, {"from": "\u0411-1", "to": "LIRA 0094RI"}, //здесь дальше очень много текста, его опустила
// adding nodes and edges to the graph
        data = {nodes: nodes, edges: edges};





        var options = {
    "configure": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "edges": {
        "color": {
            "inherit": true
        },
        "smooth": {
            "enabled": false,
            "type": "continuous"
        }
    },
    "interaction": {
        "dragNodes": true,
        "hideEdgesOnDrag": false,
        "hideNodesOnDrag": false
    },
    "physics": {
        "enabled": true,
        "stabilization": {
            "enabled": true,
            "fit": true,
            "iterations": 1000,
            "onlyDynamicEdges": false,
            "updateInterval": 50
        }
    }
};



        // default to using dot shape for nodes
        options.nodes = {
            shape: "dot"
        }


        network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);


    /*  network.on("zoom",function(){ //while zooming 
    if(network.getScale() <= 1.8% )//the limit you want to stop at
    {
        network.moveTo(afterzoomlimit); //set this limit so it stops zooming out here
    } 
});*/




        network.on("stabilizationProgress", function(params) {
            document.getElementById('loadingBar').removeAttribute("style");
            var maxWidth = 496;
            var minWidth = 20;
            var widthFactor = params.iterations/params.total;
            var width = Math.max(minWidth,maxWidth * widthFactor);

            document.getElementById('bar').style.width = width + 'px';
            document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = Math.round(widthFactor*100) + '%';
        });
        network.once("stabilizationIterationsDone", function() {
            document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '100%';
            document.getElementById('bar').style.width = '496px';
            document.getElementById('loadingBar').style.opacity = 0;
            // really clean the dom element
            setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById('loadingBar').style.display = 'none';}, 500);
        });


        return network;

    }

    drawGraph();
```